# Sliding out/in two 100% width elements at the same time

Tags: css, reactjs

I've been trying to set up this animation effect that would let me slide one element out of the screen on the left, while phasing it out onto 0 opacity and sliding in a new element at the same time from the right to take its place.

Visually, I have it working, but I also have a side effect of expanding the window width beyond that of the screen (visible by appearing horizontal scroller).
Here's a codesandbox link to a working sample with all the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-carousel-forked-9wjjob?file=/src/carousel.jsx

However, all the transitions are set up as follows:

```
  const transitions = useTransition(items, {
    from: {
      opacity: 0,
      transform: `translateX(100%)`,
      width: "100%"
    },
    enter: {
      opacity: 1,
      transform: "translateX(0%)",
      width: "100%"
    },
    leave: {
      opacity: 0,
      transform: "translateX(-100%)",
      width: "0%"
    }
  });
```

What can I do to get rid of that side-effect?

OR

How can I achieve the same visual effect without this side effect?

Answer (score 0):

Make these adjustments to the wrapper element style:

- Give it relative positioning so that the absolutely positioned child elements are positioned with respect to it instead of some other ancestor.
- Hide overflow.
- Make it tall enough to contain its children even with their 2rem top position.

  ```
  {{ height: "8rem", width: "100%", position: "relative", overflow: "hidden" }}
  ```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-carousel-forked-j0ji5k?file=/src/carousel.jsx)

You may need to tweak things to get your layout how you want it, but that handles the scroll issue.

Comment: If there are other elements below this section, wouldn't that mean that we would have an unnatural extra space there?

Comment: Yep. Absolute positioning is troublesome. Don't use it unless you have to.